# java network programming coordination of messaging

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

I have 2 processes running in different machines which are communicating via TCP sockets.
Both processes have code that acts both as a server and as a client.
I.e. **ProcessA** has opened a server socket that binds at portX and **ProcessB** has opened a server socket bind at portY.
ProcessA opens a client socket to connect with ProcessB and start sending messages as a client
and receiving responses (over the same tcp connection of course).
ProcessB once it receives a message and processes it, it sends the response, but also could send a message over the second tcp connection, i.e. where ProcessB has opened a client socket to portX of ProcessA.
So the flow of messages are over 2 different tcp connections.
My problem is the following: **Taking as granted that this "architecture" can not change and must stay as is:**
I have the problem that intermittently, the messages send from ProcessB to ProcessA over the tcp connection that ProcessB has opened the client socket, arrive at processA before the messages send as responses from ProcessB to ProcessA over the tcp connection that ProcessA has connected as a client socket.
I.e. Both flows occur

```
(1)  
ProcessA ---->(msg)----> ProcessB(PortY)  (TCP1)
ProcessB does processing   
ProcessB(portY)--->(response)----->ProcessA (TCP1)  
ProcessB--->(msg)----->ProcessA(portX)  (TCP2)

(2)  
ProcessA ---->(msg)----> ProcessB(PortY)  (TCP1)
ProcessB does processing   
ProcessB--->(msg)----->ProcessA(portX)  (TCP2)
ProcessB(portY)--->(response)----->ProcessA  (TCP1)
```

**EDIT (after ejp request)**
How can I enforce/make sure that ProcessB does not send a msg over the connection that ProcessB has a client socket open to server portX of ProcessA, before the message send as a reply from server portY of ProcessB arrives at processA? I.e. to have only flow (1) of the above.
Note that processB is multithreaded and the processing is non-trivial.

**UPDATE:** 
May be it is my misconception, but when a process sends data over socket, and control is returned to application, this does not mean that the receiving side has received the data.
So if a process sends data over 2 sockets, is there a race condition by OS?

**UPDATE2**
After answer I got from Vijay Mathew:
If I did a locking as suggested, is there a guarantee that OS (i.e. IP layer) will send the data in order? I.e. finish one transmission, then send the next? Or I would they be multiplexed and have same issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify this? Do you mean that B shouldn't send the *next* request to A via portX until the *previous* reply has arrived from A via port X? so port Y is completely irrelevant here?

Comment: @ejp:There are 2 tcp connections. B should not send msg to A via portX (opened in A) BEFORE the reply of previous message (that was send by A to B that was listening in portY) is received by A. Is this more clear? So portY is not irrelevant. It is the tcp connection that the first msg by A was send.

Comment: Your para beginning 'how can I ensure' doesn't mention port Y at all. So it doesn't agree with you've just said. Can you bring all this into agreement please? So I gather that B shouldn't send anything down port X while there is a pending reply on port Y. Is the reverse also true?

Comment: @ejp:I made an edition.Is it better now?Yes you are right on your understanding that "that B shouldn't send anything down port X while there is a pending reply on port Y". The reverse is not a requirement, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is:

```
LockObject lock;

ProcessA ---->(msg)----> ProcessB(PortY)

// Processing the request and sending its response 
// makes a single transaction.
synchronized (lock) {
    ProcessB does processing   
    ProcessB(portY)--->(response)----->ProcessA (TCP1)
}

// While the processing code holds the lock, B is not
// allowed to send a request to A.
synchronized (lock) {
    ProcessB--->(msg)----->ProcessA(portX)  (TCP2)
}
```

Comment: May be it is my misconception, but when processB hands over to OS the data to send over the socket, does control return back to the application from OS after the data has been received by the other end? No, so OS could buffer data, ProcessB would move to the second lock and then pass the data over the second socket. So there would still be some race condition, among the 2 send, right?

Answer (score 1):

The synchronisation problem may not be in the TCP protocol, but in the thread handler choosing which thread to wake up when the messages arrive.  I understand from the nature of your question that the PortX "(Msg)" is sent very quickly after after the PortY "(Response)".  This means that the thread handler may occasionally have a choice as to which of the two listening threads it will wake.

A simple, but ugly and incomplete, way to fix the problem is to insert a short sleep between the response and the next message.  The sleep would have to be long enough to be confident that the other process will have woken up to the response before the next message is received.  This way is incomplete because although you are increasing the changes of properly synchronising your processing, issues like OS load and network congestion can always conspire to push your message right back up behind your response.  And then you're back where you started.  The other bit of ugliness is that the sleeping wastes time and will reduce your maximum throughput.  Just less often.  So...

To completely resolve the issue, you need some way for each socket listener to know whether the message it just received is the next one to be processed, or whether there might be earlier messages that have to be processed first.  Do this by sequentially numbering all messages sent by each process.  Then the receiving process knows if anything is missing.

You will have to think of a way for the listeners on each socket to confer between themselves to ensure that messages received are processed in order of transmission.  There are a number of practical solutionsm, but they all amount to the same thing at the abstract, conceptual level.

THREAD 1:
A) ProcessA(PortX) thread receives a message and wakes.
B) IF the sequence number indicates that there is a missing message, THEN
B1) synchronize on ProcessA(PortY) and wait ().
B2) On waking, back to B)
C) {no message is missing} Process the message.
D) Back to A)

THREAD 2:
A) ProcessA(PortY) receives a response and wakes.
B) Process the response.
C) notifyAll ().
D) Back to A)

The most generic practical solutions would probably involve a single socket listener instance adding all new messages to a PriorityQueue so the earliest-sent messages always go to the head of the queue.  Then Thread 1 and Thread 2 could both wait on that instance until a message arrives that they can process.

A simpler but less extensible solution would be to have each thread do it's own listening and waiting with the (response) handler notifying after processing.

Good luck with it, although after all this time, it's probably solved already.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is why do you care? If you have operations that need to be synchronized at either end, do so. Don't expect TCP to do it for you, that's not what it's for.

Comment: I am not sure what you suggest.All I want to know if for example I followed Vijay Mathew suggestion, I would still get a race condition as a result of the way data are transmitted.I.e. OS would buffer both data and send them multiplexed over the wire

Comment: I am asking why in your application that would constitute a race condition in the first place. If you can't send message B before you've got an answer to message A, don't. The simplest way to ensure that is to put them both in the same piece of sequential logic. What I don't understand is why two separate processes would care about each others state.

Comment: I can not send message B before I have send a reply to previous message A.These 2 separate processes implement a single functional unit.Is this more clear?